# In use collectionView.scrollToItem and It cause a crash [UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:]

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //获取滤镜信息
    let lastCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: lastSelectIndex!) as? FilterListViewCell
    lastCell?.isSelect = false

    var filters : Array<GPUImageFilter> = []
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? FilterListViewCell
    if (lastSelectIndex == indexPath) {
        cell?.isSelect = false
        lastSelectIndex = IndexPath.init(row: -1, section: -1)
        currentFilterInfo = nil
    }else {
        filterDelegate?.didbeganApplyFilter()
        cell?.isSelect = true
        let filterInfo = filterManager.configArray[indexPath.section].filterInfos[indexPath.row]
        filters = getFilters(filterInfo: filterInfo)
        lastSelectIndex = indexPath
        currentFilterInfo = filterInfo
    }

    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    filterDelegate?.applyFilter(filters: filters)
}
```

I pretty sure that it has been layout already. and the error message is like blow.

> 0x187283e6c -[UICollectionViewData
>   layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:] + 244 1  UIKit
>   0x187495144 -[UICollectionView
>   scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:] + 260 2 
>   MagicCamera                    0x10002c8a0 specialized
>   FilterListView.collectionView(UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt :
>   IndexPath) -> () (FilterListView.swift:156) 3  MagicCamera
>   0x100029bd8 @objc FilterListView.collectionView(UICollectionView,
>   didSelectItemAt : IndexPath) -> () (FilterListView.swift) 4  UIKit
>   0x187456414 -[UICollectionView
>   _selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 608 5  UIKit                          0x187455d58 -[UICollectionView
>   touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 540 6  UIKit
>   0x1873c3458 forwardTouchMethod + 336 7  UIKit
>   0x1874110f8 -[UIResponder touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 60 8  UIKit
>   0x1873c3458 forwardTouchMethod + 336

Comment: crash in iOS 9 only

Comment: have you tried to put scrollToItem method inside the collectionview.performBatchUpdate method for iOS 9?

Comment: no, I just put scrollToItem method inside didSelectItemAt , but it's after collectionview.performBatchUpdate method